# Why this simple elastic search query returns nothing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search my database for a URL. I have documents like this:

```
    {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "medhelp",
        "_id": "AVgPTB_dMXsxewkUBUNN",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "title": "Pump minimed 404sp, 506,507,508",
            "text": "",
            "abstract": "\n            I am looking to buy one of these pump for testing purpose. It need to be in working condition. Email me if you have one for sale ***@****\n        ",
            "answers": [],
            "source": "medhelp",
            "link": "/posts/Diabetes---Type-1/Pump-minimed-404sp--506-507-508/show/2431714"
        }
```

When I search for source like this, I can get my results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "source": "medhelp"
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to do the same for the "link" field with a URL, there is always nothing returned. What's wrong with this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "link": "/posts/Diabetes---Type-1/Pump-minimed-404sp--506-507-508/show/2431714"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result of above query:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use default "standard" analyzer so value for "link" is not treated as a whole but rather as many small pieces.

**So the answer is to use "keyword" analyzer for your "link" field.**

An example how it can be accomplished is in the following code (you can execute the code one instruction at a time using Sense plugin to Chrome browser).

The most important thing is "analyzer: keyword" for "link" field mapping.
If you remove this line you will get exactly your case.

```
DELETE /test123
PUT /test123
{
      "mappings": {
          "medhelp" : {
              "properties": { 
                "link": { "type": "string"
                ,"analyzer": "keyword"
                },
                "source": { "type": "string"}
        }
    }
    }
}

GET /test123/_mapping

PUT /test123/medhelp/1
{
    "link":"/posts/Diabetes---Type-1/Pump-minimed-404sp--506-507-508/show/2431714",
    "source":"medhelp"
}

GET /test123/_search
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "link": "/posts/Diabetes---Type-1/Pump-minimed-404sp--506-507-508/show/2431714"
        }
    }
}
```